# The server tag is not well formed error in my connection string

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I am having a problem with my code when trying to run i error below:
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

it says there's an error on this line below
Line 109:        `<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=vremsdb;Initial Catalog=Survey;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Survey;Password=$urvey12345;Max Pool Size=10000"SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vSurveyQuestion] WHERE ([SubmissionID] = @SubmissionID) ORDER BY [QOrderNo]">`

Comment: Code did not publish. Error on this line  -    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=vremsdb;Initial Catalog=Survey;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Survey;Password=$urvey12345;Max Pool Size=10000"SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vSurveyQuestion] WHERE ([SubmissionID] = @SubmissionID) ORDER BY [QOrderNo]">
Line 110:            <SelectParameters>

Comment: Hey, edit your question instead.

Comment: @tufaylahmed ; for code to render correctly, you need to format it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`The server tag is not well formed` error tells that there is xml syntax error on asp.net page.

In your case there is invalid xml attribute definition. You have to add whitespace before *SelectCommand* attribute as follows:

```
ConnectionString="Data Source=vremsdb;Initial Catalog=Survey;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Survey;Password=$urvey12345;Max Pool Size=10000" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vSurveyQuestion] WHERE ([SubmissionID] = @SubmissionID) ORDER BY [QOrderNo]"
```